# Set user variable from result of query

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to set a user variable based on the result of a query in MySQL?

What I want to achieve is something like this (we can assume that both `USER` and `GROUP` are unique):

```
set @user = 123456;
set @group = select GROUP from USER where User = @user;
select * from USER where GROUP = @group;
```

Please note that I know it's possible but I do not wish to do this with nested queries.

Answer (score 394, accepted):

Yes, but you need to move the variable assignment into the query:

```
SET @user := 123456;
SELECT @group := `group` FROM user WHERE user = @user;
SELECT * FROM user WHERE `group` = @group;
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE user (`user` int, `group` int);
INSERT INTO user VALUES (123456, 5);
INSERT INTO user VALUES (111111, 5);
```

Result:

```
SET @user := 123456;
SELECT @group := `group` FROM user WHERE user = @user;
SELECT * FROM user WHERE `group` = @group;

+--------+-------+
| user   | group |
+--------+-------+
| 123456 |     5 |
| 111111 |     5 |
+--------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note that for `SET`, either `=` or `:=` can be used as the assignment operator. However inside other statements, the assignment operator must be `:=` and not `=` because `=` is treated as a comparison operator in non-SET statements.

---

**UPDATE:**

Further to comments below, you may also do the following:

```
SET @user := 123456;
SELECT `group` FROM user LIMIT 1 INTO @group; 
SELECT * FROM user WHERE `group` = @group;
```

Comment: Btw, could you suppress the output of the first statement (as its only variable assignment) and only show the output of the second query?

Comment: @Avada: Updated my answer with an alternative, which doesn't output a result for the variable assignment.

Comment: @DanielVassallo, There is also [`select grop into @group from user limit 1`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29391880/632951).

Comment: @DanielVassallo thank you so much. The statment "INTO" is very helpfull. I was looking for setting mysql var from select without returning the select. THANKS!

Answer (score 90):

Just add parenthesis around the query:

```
set @user = 123456;
set @group = (select GROUP from USER where User = @user);
select * from USER where GROUP = @group;
```

Comment: This results in `Subquery returns more than 1 row` for me

Comment: @timbroder Just add LIMIT 1 to the query. Anyway, I suggested an edit to correct that.

Answer (score 26):

First lets take a look at how can we define a variable in mysql

To define a varible in mysql
it should start with '@'  like @{variable_name} and this '{variable_name}', we can replace it with our variable name.

Now, how to assign a value in a variable in mysql. For this we have many ways to do that

1. Using keyword 'SET'.

Example :-

```sql
mysql >  SET @a = 1;
```

2. Without using keyword 'SET' and using ':='.

Example:-

```sql
mysql > @a:=1;
```

3. By using 'SELECT' statement.

Example:-

```sql
mysql > select 1 into @a;
```

Here @a is user defined variable and 1 is going to be assigned in @a.

Now how to get or select the value of @{variable_name}.

we can use select statement like

Example :-

```sql
mysql > select @a;
```

it will show the output and show the value of @a.

Now how to assign a value from a table in a variable.

For this we can use two statement like :-

1.

```sql
@a := (select emp_name from employee where emp_id = 1);
```

2. 

```sql
select emp_name into @a from employee where emp_id = 1;
```

Always be careful emp_name must return single value otherwise it will throw you a error in this type statements.

refer this:-
http://www.easysolutionweb.com/sql-pl-sql/how-to-assign-a-value-in-a-variable-in-mysql

Answer (score 13):

Use this way so that result will not be displayed while running **stored procedure.**

The query:

```sql
SELECT a.strUserID
FROM tblUsers a
WHERE a.lngUserID = lngUserID
LIMIT 1
INTO @strUserID;
```