# function in mysql (1064 error)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

The Query

```
CREATE FUNCTION AverageRateofProduct
  (  p_toDate datetime,  p_productBatchId longtext  ) 
  RETURNS decimal(18,2)  
  BEGIN  

    Declare p_averageRate decimal(18,2)  ;

    if((SELECT IFNULL(sum(inwardQuantity),0) FROM tbl_StockPosting WHERE  (date < p_toDate and  productBatchId =p_productBatchId))>0)  
        then    
        set p_averageRate = 
                            select IFNULL(sum((inwardQuantity * rate)/sum(inwardQuantity)),0)  
                            from tbl_StockPosting where (date < p_toDate and  productBatchId =p_productBatchId) ;
    END if;

    return IFNULL(p_averageRate,0)  ;
 end
```

gives and error 1064 in line 11.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'selec
t IFNULL(sum((inwardQuantity * rate)/sum(inwardQuantity)),0)
                                                        fro' at line 11
```

Comment: Please try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226079/set-the-variable-result-from-query

Answer (score 0):

change the condition I think with the below

```
if(SELECT IFNULL(sum(inwardQuantity),0) FROM tbl_StockPosting 
   WHERE (date < p_toDate and productBatchId = p_productBatchId))
```

Comment: showing error in line

select IFNULL(sum((inwardQuantity * rate)/sum(inwardQuantity)),0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 SELECT IF(inwardQuantity IS NULL,0,sum(inwardQuantity * rate) /sum(inwardQuantity))
    from tbl_StockPosting where (date < p_toDate and  productBatchId =p_productBatchId) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION AverageRateofProduct (p_toDate DATETIME, p_productBatchId LONGTEXT) RETURNS DECIMAL(18,2)  
    READS SQL DATA
BEGIN  
    DECLARE p_averageRate DECIMAL(18,2);

    IF ((SELECT IFNULL(SUM(inwardQuantity),0) FROM tbl_StockPosting sp 
         WHERE sp.date < p_toDate AND productBatchId = p_productBatchId) > 0) THEN
        SELECT IFNULL((SUM(inwardQuantity * rate)/SUM(inwardQuantity)),0) INTO p_averageRate
        FROM tbl_StockPosting sp WHERE sp.date < p_toDate AND productBatchId = p_productBatchId;
    END IF;

    RETURN IFNULL(p_averageRate,0);
END
```