# how to declare & set cursor in MYSQL STORED PROCEDURE?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I am trying to use CURSOR inside mysql stored procedure... I am getting challenge while declaring the cursor... I error is **ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';

SELECT count(*) INTO countitem from TBL_SHOPPING_CART_ITEM
   SELECT Produ' at line 8
**

Please help me to solve this issue... Thanks in advance.. my code is like below,

```
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE placeOrder(IN cartId INT)
BEGIN

   DECLARE countitem INT;
   DECLARE productId INT;
   DECLARE cartId INT;
   DECLARE itemDicountAmt INT;
   DECLARE itemCursor CURSOR;

   SET countitem = SELECT count(*) from TBL_SHOPPING_CART_ITEM
   SET itemCursor = SELECT ProductId, Quantity FROM TBL_SHOPPING_CART_ITEM
   OPEN itemCursor 
   WHILE countitem > 0
      BEGIN
         FETCH itemCursor into productId, cartId;
         itemDicountAmt = calculateNetItemStandardDiscountAmount(productId, cartId);
         insert into debugtable select concat('item discount amount', itemDicountAmt);
         SET countitem = countitem - 1;
      END
   CLOSE itemCursor 
   DEALLOCATE itemCursor    

END//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Declares must appear before any other statements and after begin.and all statements must be terminated

Comment: @P.Salmon could you please modify the code & send it back to me... it would be the great help for me.... thanks a lot for response..

Comment: Ho Ho Ho, nice one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry, this isn't a bug.
The DECLARE clause is used to tell your machine that a local variable exists. The operations are made after the declarations, by aknowledging the existing, declared local variables.

So in your case, you tried to add a new declaration of variable after the machine started calculating, which isn't possible in MySQL. You'll have to find another way to use your last variable.

To assign a new content to a variable, first use DECLARE to create your variable first, then use SET as an assignment to the declared variable. I'll leave [this link](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/15/advanced-mysql-user-variable-techniques/) right here so you can get to know how to use it.

Comment: @Riyo Shiina.. could you please modify the code ?... it would be the great help for me.... thanks a lot for your valuable suggestion..

Comment: It's not that complicated @rahulshalgar , you only have to change a few lines. You only have to move your declare before any select, and put your selected contents in a SET clause that assigns to your Cursor variable. But in your case, it's a bit complicated since what you want to store isn't really fitting the characteristics of what a variable can contain...

Comment: Yes.. the problem with declaring cursor is got resolved.. but i am getting the further error as  **ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';

   SELECT countitem = (SELECT count(*) from `CART_ITEM` WHERE `C' at line 8
**

Comment: It's because you didn't use the SET clause and used SELECT instead. SELECT can't be used to assign a value to a variable. Try it with SET !

Comment: Yes tried with SET... but again I am having the error ...... ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';

   SET countitem = (SELECT count(*) from `CART_ITEM` WHERE `Chec' at line 8
.............sorry.. I am getting your more time...

Comment: I have no idea why your error starts at ';' though, you'll have to figure it on your own. Try it with more parenthesis to make your machine understand that it's a subquery ? It apparently works that way in this topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226079/set-the-variable-result-from-query

Comment: DEClARE itemCursor CURSOR FOR 
 SELECT ProductId, Quantity FROM TBL_SHOPPING_CART_ITEM;

Comment: Oh wow, actually I didn't know you could use FOR attached to a DECLARE... That's nice you got it resolved, thanks for telling me this new solution !