# Mysql : Set user variable from result of query with multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

Further to the below question which has been answered
[MySQL: Set user variable from result of query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888735/mysql-set-user-variable-from-result-of-query)

i need to store array of comma separated values into a variable returned from a query.
for e.g

```
SET @qids := (select distinct GROUP_CONCAT(question.id, '')
from questions 
where chapter_id in(100,101,102);

select * 
from answers 
where question_id in (@qids);
```

This works but he problem is the `@qids` variable is having only one `question_id` value instead of many `question_id`'s in format like `60,61,62`

Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working with the way below

select * 
from answers 
where find_in_set (question_id,@qids);

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for that variable, you can do this, by [`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)ing the two tables `questions` and `answers` directly like this:

```
SELECT *
from questions AS Q
INNER JOIN answers AS a ON q.question_id = a.question_id
where q.chapter_id in(100, 101, 102);
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51d76f/1)

Comment: Hey Mahmoud thanks but i know about the using joins. i need the solution for my problem for a different/ larger problem i am trying to solve.the question is just an abstraction of problem

Comment: @JagdishAdusumalli - So does it work the way you want? and why do you do that this way using the `IN` predicate? and not `JOIN`ing the table directly, as I showed in my answer.