# Syntax error for MySQL function

Tags: mysql, sql, function

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION ecmsbackoffice.getSequence($delimeter VARCHAR(20)) RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
BEGIN
DECLARE result VARCHAR(20);
SET result = 0;

IF (delimeter='B') THEN UPDATE id_generator SET seq_currval=(seq_currval+1) WHERE seq_name='B';
ELSE IF (delimeter='D') THEN UPDATE id_generator SET seq_currval=(seq_currval+1) WHERE seq_name='D';
ELSE IF (delimeter='C') THEN UPDATE id_generator SET seq_currval=(seq_currval+1) WHERE seq_name='C';
END IF

SELECT seq_currval INTO result 
FROM id_generator 
WHERE seq_name = delimeter;

RETURN result;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I'm trying to create a MySQL function, but I get the following error:

> error code: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL >server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT seq_currval INTO result
>   from id_generator
>   WHERE seq_name = delimeter;
>   R' at line 9

What is the problem?

Comment: **Problem #1:** No demonstration of any troubleshooting.  **Problem #2:** Did not bother to use formatting for code when asking question.  **Problem #3:** Did not read the *help* page for an introduction to StackOverflow.  **Problem #4:** Is this really MySQL, or some other SQL that you're trying to copy-paste as a MySQL query?  **Problem #5:** Do you understand what the query is trying to do?  What are you trying to achieve (specifically, HOW are you trying to achieve it; remember, people charge hourly rates for coding, so don't make this a chore/job).  **My answer:** Syntax error.

Comment: try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888735/mysql-set-user-variable-from-result-of-query

Comment: Maybe you are just missing a semi-colon after the END IF...and therefore mysql doesn't understand the next statement (SELECT seq_...)

Comment: add semi-colon,but get the error ...
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `ELSE IF` to `ELSEIF` everywhere,

Comment: oh...!! thank you!!!
solve problem~

Comment: and i will try to use this function 
SELECT ecmsbackoffice.getSequence('D');
but i get error :(
error code: 1054
Unknown column 'delimeter' in 'field list'

one more please ...

Comment: Try to remove `$` here: `delimeter VARCHAR(20)`

Answer (score 0):

You have three open `if` statements and only one `end if`.  There is a difference between `else if` and `elseif` (note the space).  Try this:

```
IF (delimeter='B') THEN UPDATE id_generator SET seq_currval=(seq_currval+1) WHERE seq_name='B';
ELSEIF (delimeter='D') THEN UPDATE id_generator SET seq_currval=(seq_currval+1) WHERE seq_name='D';
ELSEIF (delimeter='C') THEN UPDATE id_generator SET seq_currval=(seq_currval+1) WHERE seq_name='C';
END IF;
```

Also, just for reference, the proper spelling is probably "delimiter" and not "delimeter".

Comment: and i will try to use this function 
SELECT ecmsbackoffice.getSequence('D');
but i get error :(
error code: 1054
Unknown column 'delimeter' in 'field list'

one more please ...

Comment: You don't need the `'$'` in front of the parameter name.