# MySQL Multiple Select Statements With An Update

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select the cost value of a product_id and then update the lowest value of that product_id

I need no merge these two select statements, then run an update.
I need to get the cost from one field and then multiple the formula to set the lowest price I can sell for.

```
##COST
SELECT value AS cost from catalog_product_entity_decimal
  where attribute_id = 79 and
        entity_id IN (select product_id from catalog_category_product)

##LOWEST
SELECT value AS lowest from catalog_product_entity_decimal
  where attribute_id = 164 and
        entity_id IN (select product_id from catalog_category_product)


update catalog_product_entity_decimal
   set value = (cost+3.5)/.84
   where attribute_id = 164 and
         entity_id IN (select product_id from catalog_category_product);
```

How would I go about doing this?  I'm a MySQL novice to say the least.
I've tried a UNION and Multiple Selects, but I guess I've done it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SELECT as sub-query to the UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal
SET value = ( (
    SELECT value
    FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal
    WHERE attribute_id = 79
    AND entity_id IN (select product_id from catalog_category_product)
) + 3.5 ) / .84
```

Or you can store the result from each select in a user-defined variable (`@cost`):

```
SELECT @cost := `value`
FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal
WHERE attribute_id = 79
AND entity_id IN (select product_id from catalog_category_product);

UPDATE catalog_product_entity_decimal
SET value = ( @cost + 3.5 ) / .84;
```

See also: [MySQL: Set user variable from result of query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888735/mysql-set-user-variable-from-result-of-query)

A difference between both methods is that the first one is one query while the method use two distinct queries. But both need o be executed one after the other to ensure that the variable is not overwritten by another concurrent SELECT/UPDATE operation from another request.

(Where do you use `lowest`?)

Comment: Lowest attribute id is 164 it's the one I want to update, not cost.  I need to get the cost, then do the math to update lowest

Comment: @Brad Well, use one the methods suggested and edit them…

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, I don't think your methods are going to work.  I need to select the cost value of a product_id and then update the lowest value of that product_id.