# Mysql set local variable in the select statement and return same select output with only one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have customer table and i want to return back customer info and set the same in local variables.

```
declare customerId int;

declare customerName varchar(50);
```

i.e.

```
select customerId=id, customerName=name, address, salary from customers where id=1;
```

I want to then use these local variables customerId,customerName for passing in another function.

i.e. func(customerId,customerName);

But when i select these variables in mysql SP and i get null values. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, as follows:

```
SELECT @customerId := `id`, @customerName := `name` 
FROM customers
WHERE id = 'some value';
```

The query works on the assumption that the column names are `id`, `name`.

You can follow a similar discussion on the same, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888735/mysql-set-user-variable-from-result-of-query).

**UPDATE:**
As per the change in the question, the answer is changed.

This part assigns the values that you wanted to Local SQL Variables.

```
SELECT @customerId := `id`, @customerName := `name` 
FROM customers
WHERE id = 1;
```

This part can be used as a response from your SP.

```
SELECT id, name, address, salary
FROM customers
WHERE id = 1;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do i return this select statement as output of sql sp? This sp now is not returning any output but is only assigning values. How do i do both?

Comment: After the assignment, you can either return those variables to your another SP (or) implement the logic after the assignment in the SP itself.

Comment: Your question is about assigning values of your SELECT query to variables, which I've answered. If there are further questions to you actual question, then you should go ahead ask a NEW QUESTION!

Comment: The question is actually about assigning values in SELECT and returning back same SELECT in SP output. Sorry for the confusion. I will edit the title now.