# "Subquery returns more than 1 row" when using `SET`

Tags: mysql

```
select tf.id from text_fields as tf WHERE tf.study_id NOT IN (select id from studies)
```

I'm using this to find orphaned records and it works fine.

However when I try and assign the result to a var, using `SET`, I get the "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error.

```
SET @text_field_ids := (select tf.id from text_fields as tf WHERE tf.study_id NOT IN (select id from studies))
```

For context I'm want to use the var to then text_fields records, e.g.

```
DELETE from text_fields WHERE id IN @text_field_ids
```

Incidentally I have tried passing the subquery directly to DELETE such as:

```
DELETE from text_fields WHERE id IN (select id from text_fields as tf WHERE tf.study_id NOT IN (select id from studies))
```

But this gives the error `You can't specify target table 'text_fields' for update in FROM clause` because apparently you can't use the table being deleted from in the WHERE clause.

Comment: you add "limit"

Comment: why not `DELETE from text_fields WHERE id IN (select tf.id from text_fields as tf WHERE tf.study_id NOT IN (select id from studies))`

Comment: @RehanAzherI I've just added an explanation to the question.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi `LIMIT` gives the same error, I'm adding it at the end, `(... LIMIT 100000)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the query

```
select tf.id from text_fields as tf WHERE tf.study_id NOT IN (select id from studies)
```

returns more than 1 row, assigning the recordset to a variable fails. however if you really need to assign it to a variable you can do it as

```
select `tf`.`id` from `text_fields` as tf WHERE `tf`.`study_id` NOT IN
(select `id` from `studies`) into @text_field_ids;
```

or

```
SELECT @text_field_ids := `tf`.`id` from `text_fields` as tf WHERE `tf`.`study_id` NOT IN 
(select `id` from `studies`);
```

more info about this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888735/mysql-set-user-variable-from-result-of-query)

Alternatively, If your db user has create temporary table priviliges, you can create a temporary table, to select your records into that lives through your session. Please note that not to suffer performance penalty, the temporary table is created with memory engine.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table ( INDEX(`id`) ) 
ENGINE=Memory 
AS (
    select `tf`.`id` from `text_fields` as `tf` WHERE `tf`.`study_id` NOT IN (select `id` from `studies`)
);

# and remove the records with
delete from `text_fields` where id in (select `id` from `temp_table`)
```

Comment: So a var can only contain one row... okay, that explains it, thanks. I tried the above, but `Result consisted of more than one row` :)

Comment: not necessarily, using `SET foo:=`` requires a single value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use temporary table :

```
create temporary table if not exists mytmptable select tf.id as id from text_fields as tf WHERE tf.study_id NOT IN (select id from studies)
```

and then you can use it in delete :

```
DELETE from text_fields WHERE id IN (select Id from mytmptable)
```

Comment: This works, thanks. But was surprisingly slow, not really a big issue in my case as I only had a few thousand row to delete.

Comment: Glad, it helped

Comment: if answer is correct then approve it(green tickmark)

Answer (score 1):

The usual way round a *ERROR 1093 (HY000): Table 'USERS' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data* error is to push the select a bit deeper for example see second delete below-

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT ID FROM USERS;
+----+
| ID |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
| 10 |
| 12 |
| 14 |
| 15 |
| 16 |
| 17 |
| 18 |
| 19 |
+----+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> DELETE FROM USERS
    -> WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM USERS WHERE ID IN (18,19))
    -> ;
ERROR 1093 (HY000): Table 'USERS' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> DELETE FROM USERS
    -> WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM (SELECT ID FROM USERS WHERE ID IN (18,19)) U )
    -> ;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.11 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> SELECT ID FROM USERS;
+----+
| ID |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
|  8 |
| 10 |
| 12 |
| 14 |
| 15 |
| 16 |
| 17 |
+----+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is a nice hack, imho suffers a little bit performance penalty but nevertheless a good one.

Comment: Maybe so but some sites won't let you create temporary tables.

Comment: indeed they don't