# Mysql Procedure with an input parameter and output parameter

Tags: mysql, procedure

I'm trying to Create a procedure named GetOrderItemQuantity with the previous query that takes
OrderNumber as an input parameter and the quantity of items for that order as an output
parameter.

```
    DELIMITER $$

USE `mystoredb`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GetOrderItemQuantity`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetOrderItemQuantity`(
IN orderNumber INT (11),
OUT `Items` INT (11)
)
BEGIN
SELECT
o.OrderNumber,
COUNT(oi.*) `Items`
FROM `Order` o 
LEFT JOIN orderItem oi ON o.OrderId = oi.OrderId
WHERE o.OrderNumber = orderNumber
GROUP BY o.OrderNumber;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

For some reason it doesn't seem to be functioning.

Comment: Every time you run it, it causes your house to explode?

Comment: it seems to do nothing.

Comment: But you do assign a value to the variable, and also inspect the contents of the variable after you finish calling the procedure, right? Show the code that does that (this code doesn't assign a value, or call the proc, or inspect the variable value), show what you get, show why it is different to what you expect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL: Set user variable from result of query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888735/mysql-set-user-variable-from-result-of-query)